# Problem with ChronoConnectivity V4 J3 Component

Tags: joomla-3.4, chronoforms

I already installed chronoconnectivity  V4 J3 but when i clicked on choronoconnectivity, this error appear. What should i do??

Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstAttempt\administrator\components\com_chronoconnectivity\versions\j3.4\admin.chronoconnectivity.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstAttempt\administrator\components\com_chronoconnectivity\admin.chronoconnectivity.php on line 28

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstAttempt\administrator\components\com_chronoconnectivity\versions\j3.4\admin.chronoconnectivity.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstAttempt\administrator\components\com_chronoconnectivity\admin.chronoconnectivity.php on line 28

Comment: You should contact the developer and mention this error to them

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to a new version of Joomla, you may find that ChronoForms and ChronoConnectivity start to fail or give errors. There is one solution to fix this error.

Check your ChronoForms installation and look in the /administrator/components/com_chronoforms/versions folder or the equivalent for chronoconnectivity. You will see a folders there named for different version of Joomla. If there isn't one for the new version you have upgraded to please make a copy of the previous folder and rename it to the new Joomla version.

For example copy folder j 3.3 and rename it with j 3.4 if there is no joomla 3.4 version

[image]

Based on [This link](https://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/56-cfv4/cfv4-other-faqs/5125-chronoformschronoconnectivity-fails-after-a-joomla-upgrade.html)